Is it possible to accurately describe something without describing the rest of the universe?
The obvious answer is "yes, of course", but stick with me for a moment here.
If I ask you to describe a human accurately, it is my claim that you cannot do so unless you account for the  immediate environment, and the total environment (think earth - universe respectively). This must be included in the description of a human, in order to qualify it as an accurate description. All other attempts would be lackluster, or part of the whole description.
I hold the view that this holds for all things describable by language.
I am looking for, either, someone who has dealt with this already, or arguments that show my reasoning to be wrong.
Thank you in advance, and please let me know if I am unclear, or you need more details.
EDIT: An accurate description would be one that describes the total sum of a given concept.

If your "describe accurately" demands God's level of detail then nothing real can be "accurately described" even in isolation, the rest of the universe need not apply. Any language is expressively limited and reality is inexhaustible. However, such concept of "accuracy" is neither humanly relevant nor useful.

Accurate in that it describes the total of a given thing. It is essentially an attempt to claim that humans are inseparable from the rest of the universe as since all descriptions not accounting for the whole can not accurately describe anything, it either lacks or adds on too little or too much. In the same way that I cannot describe a football accurately, without describing gravity, and so on.

"The spiritual path is like trying to swallow a porcupine: once you start, you have to eat the whole thing." - Chogyam Trungpa

@Conifold Do you think there can be accurate statements that are not detailed? "Simple" statements, if you will.

"Something exists" is one. And many statements of physics are accurate enough by humanly relevant standards.

@Conifold I agree, and it's not like we can confirm anything outside "humanly relevant standards".

Accuracy is relative. Descriptions convey limited information about an actual entity. One can describe a human with varying degrees of precision:

that it is an instance of homo sapiens
physical dimensions (height, weight, limb lengths, etc.)
appearance attributes
location in the world
posture
etc.

At each of these stages of description, the description is "accurate."

Just for the sake of clarification: Your claim is that there cannot be a description that accurately describes the totality of one thing (ie. humans)?

No, not in any practical way. If a description contained the entire concept in the way you describe, it wouldn't really be a description, but would be more complex than the thing itself. You'd be better off meeting the person than getting a description like this.
A related concept from the sciences is Bonini's paradox, which states that abstractions become less understandable, and hence less useful, as they grow to be as complex as the systems they represent (see also "All models are wrong").
In fact, if we are seeking truth beyond any model or abstraction, we arguably should prefer theories that don't describe the rest of the universe. According to at least one philosopher of science (Richard Swinburne), theories with a small scope are a priori more likely than theories with large scope, though in practice the greater simplicity of universe-wide theories more than make up for this.

Depends on what you want to describe and the LEVEL of accuracy that you aim for.
Like while you could conjecture that every single atom is subject to the forces asserted upon it by neighboring atoms and so on so that everything is subject to everything else and thus to describe one thing you'd need to describe everything.
In reality, humans are quite limited in their perception. So there is just a small window in which we can see, a small window in which we can hear, our life happens on a small window of ranges (idk without tools milimeter to kilometer) and it happens within a particular time scale (seconds to centuries).
So if an effect takes millennia or longer to come to fruition, we might not even recognize it happening because the day to day difference is so minor that it just falls under rounding errors.
So of course you can describe a concept in all it's glory without describing the entire universe, because the concept was likely created by an imperfect observer who never had the ability to include the entire universe in it to begin with.
So these things are often enough already simplifications. Like sure you could compute the force of every particle on every other particle, but realistically only the force of those in it's immediate vicinity actually produce a measurable contribution, the rest is at best some background noise that you could estimate.
The other problem is that "absolute accuracy" is an illusion anyway. Like there are hard limits as to how closely we could measure something in the first place.
Like on the quantum level we can (oversimplified) select between trapping a particle in an ever smaller box so that we know it's position with ever increasing accuracy. But what happens is that the particle bounces around in that box so violently that we have no idea how fast it is or where it's going to go if you were to lift the box. Or you could set up two lines and measure when it passes each, getting a close picture of it's speed, but would have no idea where it actually is now.
So there is an uncertainty relation that argues that the uncertainty of the position times the uncertainty of the momentum is a constant. So if you increase one your decrease the other and vice versa. But if you can't even measure position and momentum so where something is and where it is going, how do you plan to incorporate the entire universe in your description?
Similarly many physical phenomena on small scales aren't described by particular events but by probability distributions. So simplifications are not just laziness and lack of effort, they are often physical limits.
Not to mention that if you truly were to think that the universe is actually one specific entity that only ever moves as a whole and that everything is connected to everything else. Then you have the problem that you as the observer aren't actually just an observer but a part of that, so your observation messes with the "object" that you want to observe. Which further provides a problem with the idea of going towards the ever more accurate, which are effects that we already see in nature.
Like on the macro scale we measure distances and times by comparing them to other well known distances and times, but the faster and smaller you get, the fewer well known things you have to compare them to. So you measure them indirectly by their properties, which means interaction with your measuring devices, which means you become part of the experiment.
So yeah it depends on the level of accuracy, perfect accuracy is likely never to be achieved by humans.

Thank you. That was a well put reply. Could you clarify why you think there would be a problem that the observer is a part of the system?

The question would a tree make a sound if there would be no one to listen. Sounds stupid but if the observer is part of the system, the question becomes relevant as to whether you just see what happens anyway or whether you are the cause of it.

I agree that there is an implication if the observer is part of the system, not sure if it is a problem, but it is a relevant factor, for sure. But in discussing the whole system, I don't think that we can be a cause, but like everything else we are a consequence.

@Sammich As said most often a situation is considered localized so the effect of the entire universe is rather small and once you try to measure small things you get in to quantum problems where the observer measures through interaction with the object so it becomes more difficult to keep the observer out of the experiment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(quantum_physics) .

I think we are misunderstanding each other at some level here, and I don't feel able to concisely articulate what, so comments become tricky. Thank you for taking your time to reply, I appreciate your answer quite a lot.

This answer is meant to complement the other answers.  One way to look at this issue is via the Doctrine of Eternal Relations.
theory of internal relations
: the doctrine that all relations are internal and every part of reality is intrinsically related to every other part

Merrium Webster's dictionary


The doctrine of internal relations is the philosophical doctrine that all relations are internal to their bearers, in the sense that they are essential to them and the bearers would not be what they are without them. It was a term used in British philosophy around in the early 1900s
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_of_internal_relations#:~:text=The%20doctrine%20of%20internal%20relations,around%20in%20the%20early%201900s.

Basically the identity of something is not merely what makes it up, physically or other wise, but also necessarily includes the relations it has with other things.  Those are intrinsic to its identity.
I'm not presenting this as a demonstration that the answer to your question is No, but rather as a way to frame the issue.  That the relations are internal to whatever is being discussed.  Change the relations, the 'things' are not the same.
https://www.britannica.com/topic/rationalism/Religious-rationalism#ref561277
